Is this the correct process for deploying a new React Native app using Expo and EAS?
I'm new to React Native and I'm trying to deploy my first app using Expo and EAS. I've put together a process based on the documentation and some tutorials. Could you please take a look and let me know if this is the correct way to deploy a new React Native app to iOS? Any tips or best practices would be greatly appreciated!
1. Setting up a new project
I started by creating a new Expo app:
npx create-expo-app@latest helloWorld

2. Creating or linking an EAS project
Initialized EAS in the project:
eas init

This generated an app.json file. I updated it with a unique iOS app name and bundle identifier:
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "hello world App",
    "ios": {
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.example.helloworld"
    }
  }
}

3. Configuring EAS Build
Ran the build configuration:
eas build:configure

This created an eas.json file with the following content:
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 12.6.2",
    "appVersionSource": "remote"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {
      "autoIncrement": true
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}

4. Setting up credentials
Set up the necessary credentials for iOS:
eas credentials
✔ Select platform › iOS
✔ Which build profile do you want to configure? › production
✔ Using build profile: production
✔ What do you want to do? › All: Set up all the required credentials to build your project

5. Building the iOS app
Built the app locally:
eas build --platform ios --local --non-interactive

6. Publishing the iOS app
Submitted the app to Apple:
eas submit -p ios
✔ What would you like to submit? › Provide a path to a local app binary file
? Path to the app archive file (ipa): › /path/to/your/archive.ipa

Is this the right approach for deploying a new React Native app to iOS using Expo and EAS? Am I missing any crucial steps or configurations? Also, are there any common pitfalls I should watch out for during this process?
